# DynamoDB - Does the number of GSIs influence the pricing on on-demand capacity mode?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

My question is simple, instead of having one big GSI that maps several fields from many entities that I had to set common name like `field_GSI_1`, I want to create a separate GSI for each entity that I have.

So, let's consider two scenarios.

## **Scenario 1, 2 GSIs**

My_GSI_1

```
Partition Key = "pk"
Range Key = "ok"

Projected attributes = "field_gsi_1", "field_gsi_2"
```

My_GSI_2

```
Partition Key = "pk"
Range Key = "ok"

Projected attributes = "field_gsi_3", "field_gsi_4"
```

## **Scenario 2, 1 GSI**

My_GSI_1

```
Partition Key = "pk"
Range Key = "ok"

Projected attributes = "field_gsi_1", "field_gsi_2", "field_gsi_3", "field_gsi_4"
```

Question is, will Scenario 1 be more expensive in on-demand mode? Because scenario 1 is much more manageable and organized.

Of course this is only 2 GSIs, but imagine in a real scenario where I can have 10 GSIs vs 1.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a GSI as another DDB table...

So in scenario 1, for every insert you are paying for 3 writes instead of the 2 in scenario 2.

Same thing applies during updates; if field (1 or 2) and field (3 or 4) change at the same time.

I don't think two GSIs with the same key and different projections makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to "normalize" the data via GSI, wasn't aware you payed the write for the GSI replication

Comment: Actually, wouldn't the write only happens if a object has the specified attributes in the GSI? So if I insert an object that only has field_1 and field_2 it will only write to GSI 1

Comment: @Mojimi no, sparseness of a GSI applies to the keys...not the projected attributes.